# Spring boot where is my jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

Spring boot makes it really easy to setup a simple app.
But it takes me longer to actually get a jar file which I can upload to a remote server.
I am using IntelliJ, no command line, and I use gradle. The application is running somehow out of Intellij. But where are the created files? Where is my jar from Bootjar?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    // add spring data repos
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.4")

    // REST interface
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")

    // Security
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
}
```

Update: Added a picture of the project structure:

[image]

Update 2: Folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There will not be a jar created if you are just running this in your IDE. In order to do that, you need to run the gradle build (in your case) either from your IDE or the command line to get it to build it into a jar.

From the command line, go to your project directory and type this:

```
./gradlew build
```

This executes the gradle wrapper, which should download everything you need to run the build, and then executes the build.

You will then find your jar in `build/lib`

Comment: Okay I opened cmd in the folder and called 'gradlew build'. Now I've got a build dir with the jar in /build/libs. Is this also possible from IntelliJ?

Comment: @Todd I am using Intellij Idea CE but in the build folder, I am not seeing the libs folder..
yes when we do it from the terminal we can see why not in Intellij

Answer (score 0):

`build/libs`  (if you've ran build to build the jar file)